# How can I make bold and underline a string dynamically in Android code?

Tags: java, android, string

How can I make bold and italic the **Branch Name:**, **Branch No:**, **Branch Phone No:** and **Branch Timings:** in Java code? The database data should remain in simple format. These four are just headings of them. In this (current) case, it prints/displays the whole data in simple format and the user has a problem reading this data.

```
String branchInfoString = "" ;

// fetching all the database data in a list
List<BranchInfo> dbDataList = _dbHandler.getAllInfo() ;

// getting that data into a string that will be displayed in TextView
for(BranchInfo aBranch : dbDataList ){

branchInfoString = branchInfoString + 

          "Branch Name: " + aBranch.getBranchName() + "\n" +
          "Branch No: " + aBranch.getBranchNo() + "\n" + 
          "Branch Phone No: " + aBranch.getBranchPhone() + "\n" + 
          "Branch Timings: " + aBranch.getBranchTiming() + "\n" + 

          "\n --------------------------------------- \n \n" ;  

}

// showing all the branch data in a text_view
setContentView(R.layout.db_branch_list) ;
TextView dbDataView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.db_branch_list) ;
dbDataView.setText(branchInfoString) ;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can decorate the text in your TextView using HTML tags. That includes not just italics and bold, but also font color, and some other stuff. Something like this:

```
branchInfoHtmlString = branchInfoString + 

      "<b>Branch Name: " + aBranch.getBranchName() + "</b>\n" +
      "<i>Branch No: " + aBranch.getBranchNo() + "</i>\n" + 
      "<font >Branch Phone No: " + aBranch.getBranchPhone() + "</font>\n" + 
      "<font color="#FFDDDDDD">Branch Timings: " + aBranch.getBranchTiming() + "</font>\n" + 

      "\n --------------------------------------- \n \n" ;  

}

// showing all the branch data in a text_view
setContentView(R.layout.db_branch_list) ;
TextView dbDataView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.db_branch_list) ;
dbDataView.setText(Html.fromHtml(branchInfoHtmlString)) ;
```

Not all HTML tags are supported, you can find the lists of tags [here](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html) and [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use HTML content to format your text for example:

```
branchInfoString = branchInfoString + 

      "<b><i>Branch Name: </i></b>" + aBranch.getBranchName() + "\n" +
      "Branch No: " + aBranch.getBranchNo() + "\n" + 
      "Branch Phone No: " + aBranch.getBranchPhone() + "\n" + 
      "Branch Timings: " + aBranch.getBranchTiming() + "\n" + 

      "\n --------------------------------------- \n \n" ;

dbDataView.setText(Html.fromHtml(branchInfoString ));
```

Comment: thanks,.........it worked. "\n" is not working, I think I should use the </br> tag here

Answer (score 0):

You can format your string and set it in textview

```
String some_string = Html.fromHtml(YourHTMLFromattedString)
dbDataView.setText(some_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [Html.fromHtml(String source)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) and HTML `<b></b>` and `<i></i>` tag for showing some Text in bold and italic as

```
for(BranchInfo aBranch : dbDataList ){

branchInfoString = branchInfoString + 

          "<b><i>Branch Name: </i></b>" + aBranch.getBranchName() + "\n" +
          "<b><i>Branch No: </i></b>" + aBranch.getBranchNo() + "\n" + 
          "<b><i>Branch Phone No: </i></b>" + aBranch.getBranchPhone() + "\n" + 
          "<b><i>Branch Timings: </i></b> " + aBranch.getBranchTiming() + "\n" + 

          "\n --------------------------------------- \n \n" ;  

}

//your code ...

dbDataView.setText(Html.fromHtml(branchInfoString)) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a tableView with multiple rows that would be added at runtime. The first row would contain the column headings.

Ex.

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/class">
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/headers">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/branch_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:typeface="serif">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/branch_no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:typeface="serif">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/branch_phone_no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:typeface="serif">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/branch_timings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:typeface="serif">
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

and to add the data to this table, in the class, you would add something like this :

```
TableLayout layout =     (TableLayout)LayoutInflater.from(canvas.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.class, null);

TableRow headerRow = (TableRow) layout.findViewById(R.id.header);
TextView branchName = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.branch_name);
TextView branchNo = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.branch_no);
TextView branchPhoneNo = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.branch_phone_no);
TextView branchTimings = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.branch_timings);

branchName.setText("Branch Name");
branchName.setTypeFace(null, Typeface.BOLD);

branchNo.setText("Branch No");
branchNo.setTypeFace(null, Typeface.BOLD);

branchPhoneNo.setText("Branch Phone No");
branchPhoneNo.setTypeFace(null, Typeface.BOLD);

branchTimings.setText("Branch Timimgs");
branchTimings.setTypeFace(null, Typeface.BOLD);


for (int i=0; i<noOfRows; i++) {
    TableRow dataset = new TableRow(context);
    TextView branchName = new TextView(context);
    TextView branchNo = new TextView(context);
    TextView branchPhoneNo = new TextView(context);
    TextView branchTimings = new TextView(context);

    branchName.setText("SampleBranchName" + i);
    branchNo.setText("SampleNumber" + i);
    branchPhoneNo.setText("SamplePhoneNumber" + i);
    branchTimings.setText("SampleTimings" + i);

    dataset.addView(branchName);
    dataset.addView(branchNo);
    dataset.addView(branchPhoneNo);
    dataset.addView(branchTimings);

    layout.addView(dataset);
}
```

Comment: Does this dynamically print the values? I mean for, let say, we have 1000-branchNames, 1000-branchNo,.... in the database. Does this print all the data below the other? I tried only <RelativeLayout> but it printed each new value on the previous one :)

Comment: What this would do is add a new table row for each record. So this would not over-write on the previous one :) This is the core android way of doing it. Pls feel free to tag this ans. as useful/correct if it has helped you.